# python and («») symbols in text file

Tags: python, character-encoding

i load into text file data from database. it is in utf-8. Now how i can read this text file in python consider it contains mention in title symbols?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`codecs.open`](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#codecs.open):

```
codecs.open(filename, encoding='utf-8', mode='r')
```

Comment: tried still problem with converting to unicode and print put. it is unresolvable just a bug with python.

Comment: @simar the file returned by `codecs.open` will give you the data already in unicode.

Comment: @simar: it's not a bug in python. If there's "a problem" (what kind of problem?), it's a problem with your code. Are you sure the file is encoded in utf-8?